# Modify a part of a file with BeautifulSoup - Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I need to modify a part of a html file. I manage to do it with BeautifulSoup like this:

```
def ineedhelp(path):
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    #Retrieve htmlFiles
    pages = find_files(path, '.html') #as a list

    for page in pages:
        stream = open(page, "rw")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(stream, "lxml")
        formsoup = soup.find('form', attrs={"method":u"post"})
        if formsoup is not None:
           action = formsoup['action']
           phpScript = init_php(path, page, action) #Function that return URL as a string

         ##### HERE I TRY TO DO THIS ####
Something like: -formsoup['action'] = phpScript
                -Save the result

    stream.close()
```

The way I did it is the only I found which work in my case, if I try a:

```
for form in soup.find('form', attrs={whatever})
```

I have an error message like "None objects can't be iterated".

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over a tag, instead of an array.  `find` returns a tag, `findAll` returns an array of tags.

You can change:

```
for form in soup.find('form', attrs={whatever})
```

to:

```
form = soup.find('form', attrs={whatever})
```

> Or

You can change:

```
for form in soup.find('form', attrs={whatever})
```

to:

```
form form in soup.findAll('form', attrs={whatever})
```

Depending on how many forms there are.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Any idea of how I can save it to my file ?